# show data in v-for only in 3 rows horizontally

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, v-for

i want to show the data in total of 3 rows with the v-for loop

this is the way will be displayed

[image]

whats happening is if more data comes in 4th row will be created but i want the data to be displayed only in these 3 rows and on click the next button show the data. i have tried computed properties to send data in chunks but nothing works. Kindly put some light on it

```
backgrounds:[
    {
      route:'/events',
      img:'/images/events.png',
      caption:'Veranstaltungen'
    },
    {
      route:'/',
      img:'/images/bilder.png',
      caption:'Bildergalerie'
    },
    {
      id:103,
      route:'companies',
      img:'/images/markenbetriebe.png',
      caption:'Vulkanland Markenbetriebe'
    },
    {
      id:101,
      route:'companies',
      img:'/images/gastro.png',
      caption:'Gastronomiebetriebe'
    },
    {
      id:102,
      route:'companies',
      img:'/images/naechtigungen.png',
      caption:'Nächtigung'
    },
    {
      id:115,
      img:'/images/buschenschank.png',
      caption:'Buschenschenken'
    },
    {
      route:'/',
      img:'/images/sehenswuerdigkeit.png',
      caption:'Sehenswürdigkeiten'
    },
    {
      id:104,
      route:'companies',
      img:'/images/bauern.png',
      caption:'Direktvermarkter'
    },
    {
      id:106,
      route:'companies',
      img:'/images/touriteninfo.png',
      caption:'Touristeninformation'
    },
    {
      id:109,
      route:'companies',
      img:'/images/kulture.png',
      caption:'Kulturhäuser'
    },
    {
      id:107,
      route:'companies',
      img:'/images/sport.png',
      caption:'Sport und Spiel'
    },
    {
      id:113,
      route:'companies',
      img:'/images/handel.png',
      caption:'Handelsbetriebe'
    },
    {
      id:114,
      route:'companies',
      img:'/images/gewerbebetriebe.png',
      caption:'Gewerbebetriebe'
    },
    {
      route: '/',
      img:'/images/Button-1.png',
      caption:'Schaukästen'
    },
  ]
```

Comment: This has a small part around Vue itself. More of a CSS issue tbh.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for a naive and quick 3 elements per row display

```html
<template>
  <section class="three-elements-per-row">
    <div
      v-for="background in backgrounds"
      :key="background.route"
      class="element"
    >
      {{ background.caption }}
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      backgrounds: [
        {
          route: '/events',
          img: '/images/events.png',
          caption: 'Veranstaltungen',
        },
        {
          route: '/',
          img: '/images/bilder.png',
          caption: 'Bildergalerie',
        },
        {
          id: 103,
          route: 'companies',
          img: '/images/markenbetriebe.png',
          caption: 'Vulkanland Markenbetriebe',
        },
        {
          id: 101,
          route: 'companies',
          img: '/images/gastro.png',
          caption: 'Gastronomiebetriebe',
        },
        {
          id: 102,
          route: 'companies',
          img: '/images/naechtigungen.png',
          caption: 'Nächtigung',
        },
        {
          id: 115,
          img: '/images/buschenschank.png',
          caption: 'Buschenschenken',
        },
        {
          route: '/',
          img: '/images/sehenswuerdigkeit.png',
          caption: 'Sehenswürdigkeiten',
        },
        {
          id: 104,
          route: 'companies',
          img: '/images/bauern.png',
          caption: 'Direktvermarkter',
        },
        {
          id: 106,
          route: 'companies',
          img: '/images/touriteninfo.png',
          caption: 'Touristeninformation',
        },
        {
          id: 109,
          route: 'companies',
          img: '/images/kulture.png',
          caption: 'Kulturhäuser',
        },
        {
          id: 107,
          route: 'companies',
          img: '/images/sport.png',
          caption: 'Sport und Spiel',
        },
        {
          id: 113,
          route: 'companies',
          img: '/images/handel.png',
          caption: 'Handelsbetriebe',
        },
        {
          id: 114,
          route: 'companies',
          img: '/images/gewerbebetriebe.png',
          caption: 'Gewerbebetriebe',
        },
        {
          route: '/',
          img: '/images/Button-1.png',
          caption: 'Schaukästen',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.three-elements-per-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}
.element {
  background: seagreen;
  border: 2px solid paleturquoise;
}
</style>
```

And this is how it looks

[image]

Quick guide on CSS grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

---

[That one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74336880/8816585) is maybe a more flexible solution overall (more responsive).