# Dynamic list rendering in VueJS

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to display the images and its content in a web page (VueJS). I am having a problem with display them in a row with maximum number of elements for each row is 4.

```html
<div className="container" style="padding-top: 1rem; width: 100%; min-height: 600px">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="card" style="width: 15rem; height: 15rem; margin: 20px" v-for="(image, index) in allImagesData"
           :key="index">
        <img class="card-img-top" :src='image.media_url' alt="Image" style="max-height: 12rem; max-width: 10rem;">
        <p>{{ image.platform }}</p>
        <p>{{ image.count }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The images shows in a vertically, I need to have it in horizontally.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this to display the images in horizontally. The list will have different number of elements each time.

Comment: This post from yesterday is quite similar, may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74332768/8816585

Answer (score 1):

Try to set flex on column:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      allImagesData: [{platform: 1, count:1, media_url: 'https://picsum.photos/200'}, {platform: 5, count:5, media_url: 'https://picsum.photos/200'}, {platform: 2, count:2, media_url: 'https://picsum.photos/200'}, {platform: 3, count:3, media_url: 'https://picsum.photos/200'}, {platform: 4, count:4, media_url: 'https://picsum.photos/200'}],
    };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card {
  flex: 1 0 21%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div className="container" style="padding-top: 1rem; width: 100%; min-height: 600px">
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="card" style="max-width: 15em; height: 15em; margin: 20px" v-for="(image, index) in allImagesData"
             :key="index">
          <img class="card-img-top" :src='image.media_url' alt="Image" style="max-height: 12rem; max-width: 10rem; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px;">
          <p>{{ image.platform }}</p>
          <p>{{ image.count }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: display: flex;    this works well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine

```html
<template>
  <div class="columns">
    <div v-for="image in allImagesData" :key="image.platform" class="column">
      <img class="fitting-image" :src="image.media_url" />
      <p>{{ image.platform }}</p>
      <p>{{ image.count }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      allImagesData: [
        {
          platform: 'facebook',
          media_url: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=1',
          count: 12,
        },
        {
          platform: 'twitter',
          media_url: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=2',
          count: 15,
        },
        {
          platform: 'instagram',
          media_url: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=3',
          count: 4,
        },
        {
          platform: 'mastodon',
          media_url: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=4',
          count: 664,
        },
        {
          platform: 'discord',
          media_url: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=5',
          count: 15,
        },
        {
          platform: 'discord2',
          media_url: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=6',
          count: 15,
        },
        {
          platform: 'discord3',
          media_url: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=7',
          count: 15,
        },
        {
          platform: 'discord4',
          media_url: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=8',
          count: 15,
        },
        {
          platform: 'discord5',
          media_url: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=9',
          count: 15,
        },
        {
          platform: 'discord6',
          media_url: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=10',
          count: 15,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.columns {
  display: grid;
  --gap: 1rem; /* update this variable to create more/less distance with elements */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, calc(25% - var(--gap))));
  gap: var(--gap);
}
.column {
  background: paleturquoise;
  border: 3px solid tomato;
}
.fitting-image {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Looks like this (with the devtools grid layout overlay)

[image]

[Stays at 25% on all screen sizes](https://share.cleanshot.com/w8HDk0) and is easy to toggle the gap in between each elements.